# Count the smiley faces in an array. If in array problem

Tags: python, string

Description:

> Given an array (`arr`) as an argument complete the function
> `countSmileys` that should return the total number of smiling faces.
>
> Rules for a smiling face:
>
> - Each smiley face must contain a valid pair of eyes. Eyes can be marked as `:` or `;`
> - A smiley face can have a nose but it does not have to. Valid characters for a nose are `-` or `~`
> - Every smiling face must have a smiling mouth that should be marked with either `)` or `D`.

Here is my code:

```
def count_smileys(arr):
    counter = 0
    for e in arr:
        if e[0] in [':',';'] and e[-1] in ['D',')']:
            counter +=1
    return counter
```

Why doesn't this code return the right answer? Where is the mistake?

Comment: can you share the input and output?

Comment: Should `":o)"` be counted as a smiley? Should `":------------D"`?

Comment: Please read [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/48428) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: you may have smileys in the middle of your string. e could be ' :) ' or '_;-)-' and your algorithm wouldn't count it. It really depends on the pre-conditions of the excercise they gave you

Comment: @jonrsharpe this smiley remind me of something else :p

Comment: @sahasrara62 I'm sure I don't know what you mean `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

Your Logical is absolutely correct, but we need optional condition for nose as you said in the statement that nose is optional.

```
def count_smileys(arr):
 valid_smileys=[]
 count = 0
 for e in arr:
         
     if e[0] in [':',';'] and e[-1] in ['D',')'] and e[1] in ['~','-']:
         count=count+1
         valid_smileys.append(e)
     elif e[0] in [':',';'] and e[-1] in ['D',')'] and len(arr)==2:
         count=count+1
         valid_smileys.append(e)
 print(f'Valid smileys are: {valid_smileys}')

 return count 

arr=[':-D',':-)',':~D',':D',';--',':-']
print(count_smileys(arr))
```

OUTPUT:

Valid smileys are: [':-D', ':-)', ':~D']
3